# Is it possible to read the contents of a Google Apps Script from another Script

Tags: google-apps-script, mime, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way to read the contents of the script.gs files within a standalone Google Apps Script. I can't find a suitable getAs() Mime format in the Docslist.File service that doesn't fail. The context of this is that I want to use the html service/content service to be able to embed public GAS source samples in Google Sites and elsewhere. (in much the same way as embedding Gist Samples). Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is, in fact, possible. This gets Code.gs:

```
function myFunction() {
  throw ScriptApp.getResource("Code").getDataAsString();
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this now. Works great. http://excelramblings.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/google-apps-script-new-day-new-feature.html

Comment: There is a "GAS Library Management" that implements the Corey's solution: https://sites.google.com/site/nnillixxsource/Roberts/RoseCMMSv020/global/getCode_js

Comment: I think this functionality has been removed. I cannot find it anymore. Is there an alternative?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, or included in the Typescript type definition for `ScriptApp`, but I just tested this in an Apps Script project and it does work (Aug 2023)

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to programmatically retrieve the contents of a ".gs" file. You can only ask for files with ".html" extension and potentially you can return it in a project.

This request has come up in the context of allow local development or Git integration to provide an API way to get/set script source in a file. Please put your comments in this issue tracker request or log a new one if it makes sense .

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1108

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the request you linked to is moe abou being able to update apps script code using some version control system. I can see this might be useful, but my request,is a little simpler. I just want to be able to read the contents of a script. Thanks for the pointer though. I will raise a,separate rfq.