# How to reuse a single JavaScript in both server and client components of G Suite Add-on?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, module, maintainability, google-apps-script-addon

I have a JavaScript file that's a generated parser (let's call it `MyParser`), which I am using in an add-on for Google Forms.

It needs to be used in the client side's `Sidebar.html` where I'm including it with `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MyParser.js').getContent();`, which means it must be an `.html` file as far as I understand. Then it must be used on the server side where I have it in a file `MyParser.js.gs`.

With my current solution, it's duplicated in my file structure:

```
Code.gs
MyParser.js.gs
MyParser.js.html
Sidebar.html
```

Is there a way I can make this work without having two files? **Edit:** As I understand it, [libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) are only for the server side.

If not, any hints to making the updating of the two files more robust (currently it's manual copy/paste)?

**Edit**: According to the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices), one must wrap the JavaScript inside a `<script>` tag inside the `.html` file:

> Notice that the included files contain `<style>` and `<script>` tags because they're HTML snippets and not pure .css or .js files.

So it seems it's not easy to have just one file.

Comment: I use browserify.org plugin to run the same javascript code on the client and server-side. I would suggest trying to use Browserify and post any issues with code samples.

Comment: Switch to local development with [@google/clasp](https://GitHub.com/Google/clasp) and you can create a workflow where you auto-generate the HTML version from the JS version using normal dev tools like webpack or browserify or roll-up or grunt or ....

Comment: @StevenFriedman it doesn't sound like you've used it in Google Apps Script (with CAJA - it strips a lot of stuff out for security and compatibility). Before anyone explores that rabbit hole, can you verify you've used it in GAS?

Comment: I haven’t used it in GAS, I was just providing a possible approach that might be helpful.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks! My life has changed. You make your comment an answer and I'll accept. By the way, once an add-on is published, to update it, is it as easy as `clasp deploy n ...` (`n` is version)?

Comment: Feel free to self answer and provide an actual example rather than handwaving 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could tell, there's no way to reuse a single file and respect Google's best practices.

My solution, following @tehhowch's advice, was with [@google/clasp](https://github.com/Google/clasp) and doing local development.

To build the parser (in another GitHub project), I use [npm-run-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script). So, I just appended a `&& bash makeHTML.sh` to the `build` script.

Inside `makeHTML.sh` I wrapped the built `MyParser.js` file in a `<script>` tag with:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{ echo "<script>"; cat MyParser.js; echo "</script>"; } > MyParser.js.html
```

Since I'm using `bash` it's not a true `node.js` solution (won't run unless there's bash installed). If someone knows of a better way to pull off the wrapping that's 100% node and doesn't require installing a whole bunch of other modules, feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As your add-on has just few files you might use `ScriptApp.getResource(filename).getDataAsString()` to get the content of a .gs file and add it to the sidebar `HttpOutput` object enclosed in `<script>` tags.

Code.gs

```
function showSidebar(){
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>My Sidebar content</h1>');
  .append(`<script>${ScriptApp.getResource('JavaScript').getDataAsString()}</script>`);
  SpreadsheetApp.showSidebar(htmlOutput,'My Sidebar');
}
```

JavaScript.gs
To keep things simple, this file should contain only reusable (server-side + cliente-side) JavaScript

```
function myFunction(){
  console.log('My function ran successfully');
}
```

The above over simplistic code example might be applied to a bit more complex projects and will keep you away from having to use CLASP.

Contrary as happens with .gs and .html files, so far I was unable to make `ScriptApp.getResource(filename).getDataAsString()` to work to pull reusable JavaScript from .gs files hosted on a Google Apps Script library. Anyway, it's still possible to stay away of CLASP, one option might be to use Advanced Service Google Apps Script API, another might be to host the shared JavaScript and imported from Google Drive or from another host by using Url Fetch service.

Related

- [Is it possible to read the contents of a Google Apps Script from another Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13210469/1595451)
- [HTML and JavaScript from another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62917158/1595451)
- [Server side HTML Form validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73759058/1595451)

Comment: Actually, I'm happy now that I use clasp (makes it easier to maintain the code and make it open). But it's good to have a no-clasp solution.